# How to control camera view

Tags: 3d-view, camera

I am right clicking, but I can't seem to rotate or move the camera at all. Any ideas? Blender only seems to be able to move objects and lights. Really confused since I'm new. Please help me if you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you probably should of read the manual, not that I can say much. But to control the camera view is not right click. Its the middle mouse button. If you dont have one you can use your arrows on the control to move around. For more information about navigation, you can read this manual: 
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/navigate/index.html

And here is the full manual for help on anything else you might need:
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/

Comment: Wow that was a fast response, but I thanks. I seriously thought it was right click to move around, I don't have a middle mouse button since I use a laptop, so its good that I can use the control pad to move around. I'll try reading the manual to understand it better.

Comment: yea, I just got on the website and saw this question, I hardly get blender and I am actually having a problem right now, but if you could, can you accept my answer? I want the teacher badge lol.

Answer (score 2):

1. View -> Camera (or <kbd>Numpad 0</kbd>)
2. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> (enter flight mode)
3. WASD to control camera and leftmouse to set the view

Answer (score 0):

You can right click the camera, then key <kbd>G</kbd> to grab it, or use the translate controls to position it.

Answer (score 0):

you must choose camera view by
- clicking on the small camera icon on right top of the viewport
- hit N on the keyboard
- and check Lock camera to view
than orbit as usually